# How do I resolve all the dropdown menu opening at the same time in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created an application which is used to get your tasks in form of todo lists. These lists can be edited and deleted. I wanted to add a dropdown menu in the list which helps us to access the list update or delete page. But the Problem is whenever I click the dropdown Icon the dropdown menus of all the lists are opening at the same time. Can anybody help me resolve this issue. I am attaching my Vue.JS code here and my screenshot of the dashboard in which the lists are present.

DashboardView.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <Navbar class="navbar__dash" />
    <h1 class="dashboard__welcome">Welcome {{ name }}</h1>
    <div class="listview">
      <div class="no__lists" v-if="len_list === 0">
        <h2 class="no_lists">There are No lists here tap to add</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="has__lists" v-else>
        <div class="all__lists" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <div class="list">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="title__options">
                <h1 class="list_name">{{ item.list_name }}</h1>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button @click="toggleMenu">
                    <fa class="dropdown_icon" icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-down" />
                  </button>
                  <div v-if="showMenu" class="menu">
                    <div
                      class="menu-item"
                      v-for="(item, index) in links_list"
                      :key="index"
                      @click="itemClicked"
                    >
                      {{ item.title }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- V-menu -->
                <!--menu ends-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <div class="no_tasks" v-if="item.no_of_tasks === 0">
                <h3>There are no tasks added yet</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="has_tasks" v-else>
                <h4>Here are your tasks</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
              Number of Completed tasks: {{ item.no_completed }}/{{
                item.no_of_tasks
              }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-link :to="`/createList/${id}`">
        <fa class="plus__icon" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

import Navbar from '../components/NavBar.vue';
export default {
  name: 'DashboardView',
  data() {
    return {
      name: localStorage['name'],
      len_list: 0,
      items: [],
      id: localStorage['id'],
      links_list: [{ title: 'Click Me' }, { title: 'Click Me' }],
      showMenu: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getTrackers() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard/' + localStorage['id'];
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.items = res.data.list;
          console.log(res.data.list);
          this.len_list = res.data.list[0]['len_list'];
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      console.log(this.items);
    },
    toggleMenu() {
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    },
    itemClicked() {
      this.toggleMenu();
    },
  },
  components: {
    Navbar,
  },
  created() {
    this.getTrackers();
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #ffd700;
  background-image: url('../assets/wood-texture.jpg');
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.dashboard__welcome {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.plus__icon {
  margin-left: 58rem;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #ffd700;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffd700;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.no_lists {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15rem;
}

.navbar__dash {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  max-width: inherit;
}
.has__lists {
  display: flex;
}
.list {
  padding: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffd700;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.title {
  background: #ffd700;
  color: black;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -10rem;
  margin-top: -10rem;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
}
.footer {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  background: #ffd700;
  color: black;
  width: 320px;
  margin-left: -10rem;
  margin-top: 0.01rem;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 320px;
  color: grey;
  margin-left: -10rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10rem;
}
.list_name {
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  padding: 2px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.list__icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.title__options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.dropdown_icon {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  color: #ffd700;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: var(--transition);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
.dropdown_icon:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  height: 20px;
}
.menu {
  background: white;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

Screenshots:

[image: Dashboard]
[image: Dashboard with dropdown button clicked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for each of the lists to act independently, you should isolate the relevant code. The most logical thing would be to isolate the part of the code that displays the items. The logic being isolated, each item would have its own `showMenu` variable, allowing only one of them to be acted upon at a time.

Component Parent

```js
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <Navbar class="navbar__dash" />
    <h1 class="dashboard__welcome">Welcome {{ name }}</h1>
    <div class="listview">
      <div class="no__lists" v-if="len_list === 0">
        <h2 class="no_lists">There are No lists here tap to add</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="has__lists" v-else>
        <div class="all__lists" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <Items :item="item"/> //Call Component Items
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-link :to="`/createList/${id}`">
        <fa class="plus__icon" icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

import Navbar from "../components/NavBar.vue";
export default {
  name: "DashboardView",
  data() {
    return {
      name: localStorage["name"],
      len_list: 0,
      items: [],
      id: localStorage["id"],
      links_list: [{ title: "Click Me" }, { title: "Click Me" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getTrackers() {
      const path = "http://localhost:5000/dashboard/" + localStorage["id"];
      axios
        .get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.items = res.data.list;
          console.log(res.data.list);
          this.len_list = res.data.list[0]["len_list"];
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      console.log(this.items);
    }
  },
  components: {
    Navbar, Items
  },
  created() {
    this.getTrackers();
  },
};
</script>
```

Component Child (Items)

```js
<template>
<div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="title__options">
        <h1 class="list_name">{{ item.list_name }}</h1>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button @click="toggleMenu">
            <fa class="dropdown_icon" icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-down" />
          </button>
          <div v-if="showMenu" class="menu">
            <div
              class="menu-item"
              v-for="(item, index) in links_list"
              :key="index"
              @click="itemClicked"
            >
              {{ item.title }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="no_tasks" v-if="item.no_of_tasks === 0">
        <h3>There are no tasks added yet</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="has_tasks" v-else>
        <h4>Here are your tasks</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Number of Completed tasks: {{ item.no_completed }}/{{ item.no_of_tasks }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  props: {
    item: Item,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggleMenu() {
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    },
    itemClicked() {
      this.toggleMenu();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```